# Alamofire 4.5.1 Upload MultipartFormData Response Handling

Tags: xcode, swift3, alamofire, multipartform-data, xcode9

I am using Xcode Version 9.0, Swift 3.2. I want to upload a zip file to specified URL and get response after server side processes are made.

I am able to send request and upload file. Unfortunately, I could not handle response. I came across various situations which are listed below.

Trial #1

```
        Alamofire.upload(
        multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
            multipartFormData.append(fileURL, withName: "encrypted_images")
    },
        to: "http://" + self.se.getIpAndPort() + "/enroll",
        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload
                    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (result) in
                        print("Start of responseJSON")
                        print(result)

                        do {
                            let readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result.data!, options:.allowFragments) as! [String: Any]
                            let rStatus = readableJSON["status"] as! String
                            if rStatus == "Done" {
                                print("Status:Done")
                                self.endOfUploadRunFunctions(errorFlag: false)
                            }
                        }catch{
                            print("Status:Error")
                            self.endOfUploadRunFunctions(errorFlag: true)
                        }
                        print("End of responseJSON!")

                    })

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("Failure")
                print(encodingResult)
                if encodingError._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    print("Timeout error!")
                }
                print(encodingError)
                self.endOfUploadRunFunctions(errorFlag: true)
            }
    }
    )
```

Output #1

```
2017-10-16 16:55:36.558671+0300 MyApp Data[5500:1367406] Task <6A1894B9-7185-4B39-AD68-480548A1DAA3>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
Start of responseJSON
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x1c044dd10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.115.1:9090/enroll, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.115.1:9090/enroll, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
Status:Error
End of responseJSON!
```

ServerSide #1

It continues processing. Nothing returned yet as response from server to the app.

Trial #2

I created another class in order to change timeout. It's just a wrapper class to set time intervals to wait for a response.

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

class NetworkManager {

    var manager: SessionManager

    init() {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 200
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 200 // seconds
        manager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

Just changed the way how I call upload function. I initiated object within class and used that SessionManager object to call upload method of Alamofire.

```
self.networkOperator.manager.upload(
            multipartFormData: { multipartFor...
```

Output #2

```
2017-10-16 17:25:44.832541+0300 MyApp Data[5529:1377171] Task <448D0EF9-00D6-4E86-BD40-6E4A612892B5>.<1> finished with error - code: -1001
Start of responseJSON
FAILURE: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.115.1:9090/enroll, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.115.1:9090/enroll, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2103, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}
Status:Error
End of responseJSON!
```

ServerSide #2

It has finished processing before output printed to the Xcode console. Server has returned HTTP 200 and status as Done using JSON formatted answer.

I have tried changing timeout intervals as 600 and it gave same results. Server says "OK", but app says "Timeout error".

I have also done another test to understand system works or not. I ignored processes in server side and just returned Done. It works perfectly. But I have to do some jobs within server, so app should wait for response.

I have alse tested Alamofire-Synchronous. Yes, it does not work either.

What I am missing? I have seen some topics about Alamofire works asynchron and it is not thread safe. So what should I do to handle this situation?

Thanks

Comment: I'm seeing this as well.  Weird thing is only on iOS 11.0.  On newest version of iOS simulator asynchronous call comes back without error.